# How to test ticket before printing without physical printing using ESC_POS_PRINTER package on flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, thermal-printer

I'm using [esc_pos_bluetooth](https://pub.dev/packages/esc_pos_bluetooth) in my flutter application , i don't wan't to spend a paper every time i test print a ticket , is there anyway to export the ticket a PDF or image to be able to check it without burning a paper ? here is my code :

```dart
class PrintingServices {
  PrinterBluetooth printer;
  MoneyCollectingTicket moneyCollectingTicket;

  PrintingServices({this.moneyCollectingTicket});

  Ticket prepareMoneyCollectionData() {
    final Ticket ticket = Ticket(PaperSize.mm80);

    ticket.text( "Order time: ${moneyCollectingTicket.date}",
        styles: PosStyles(codeTable: PosCodeTable.westEur));
    ticket.text('Special 2: blåbærgrød',
        styles: PosStyles(codeTable: PosCodeTable.westEur));

    ticket.text('Bold text', styles: PosStyles(bold: true));
    ticket.text('Reverse text', styles: PosStyles(reverse: true));
    ticket.text('Underlined text',
        styles: PosStyles(underline: true), linesAfter: 1);
    ticket.text('Align left', styles: PosStyles(align: PosAlign.left));
    ticket.text('Align center', styles: PosStyles(align: PosAlign.center));
    ticket.text('Align right',
        styles: PosStyles(align: PosAlign.right), linesAfter: 1);

    ticket.text('Text size 200%',
        styles: PosStyles(
          height: PosTextSize.size2,
          width: PosTextSize.size2,
        ));

    ticket.feed(2);
    ticket.cut();
    return ticket;
  }
  Future<void> printMoneyCollectionData() async {
    PrinterBluetoothManager printerManager = PrinterBluetoothManager();
    printerManager.scanResults.listen((printers) async {
      printer = printers[0];
    });
    printerManager.startScan(Duration(seconds: 4));
    printerManager.selectPrinter(printer);
    final PosPrintResult res = await printerManager.printTicket(prepareMoneyCollectionData());
    print('Print result: ${res.msg}');
  }
}
```

As you see this code finds a physical printer , what i need to change to export it to a file ?